# Saving data in TXT file using python to the local driver

Tags: python

i make a simple code in python to output data in txt format file in my local driver pc using windows OS but nothing happened . i want to know the problem

here is the code :

```
f = open("my.txt" , "w")

def a():

    return (2+3)

def x():

    b = a()
    print("\n" ,b)

f.write(x())
f.close()
```

Comment: Mohamed, you can write strings to a file, your function x() does not return a string.

Comment: just return `"{}\n".format(a())` or `"\n{}".format(a())`

Comment: You're not returning anything in function x. Change `print("\n" ,b)` with `return "\n" + str(b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this

```
f = open("my.txt" , "w")
def a():
    return (2+3)
def x():
    b = a()
    print("\n" ,b)
    return str(b)
f.write(x())
f.close()
```

since function x does not return anything you cant print it to file

Answer (score 0):

Writing into files both strings and variables.
*Please Note:* There are many ways to get it done. This is just one.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

# function returning compute results
def fun_compute(num):
    return num * num

# For writing in a file.
# Opened the file in w+ mode
with open("./files/sample.txt", "w+") as sys.stdout:
    print("I am printing fun stuff!")  # writing standard string
    num = 5
    for n in range(num):
        print("fun_compute for - %s" % fun_compute(n))
```

Comment: Use [redirect_stdout](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) instead of `as sys.stdout`